# SF Story Early 80s - Trying to develop an anti-venom for a 100% fatal alien creature

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am seeking a science fiction book I read in the 1980s. I am pretty sure it was at least novella length if not a full novel. I don't know how old it was at the time I read it.

In it, an alien planet contains a remnant human colony which has somehow survived despite the presence of an alien creature whose bite appears to be 100% fatal. The animals are named after the first off-world victim, but I cannot remember the name. I am thinking something along the lines of a Frederik Pohl type story, but nothing I have researched seems to ring a bell.

The planet apart from the venomous alien animals is otherwise a paradise. Hence, the basis for the story. The government and industry wants to colonize the planet, but cannot because of the venomous animals. They are desperately working to synthesize an anti-venom to counteract the bite. A young researcher who comes to the planet is helping to capture some of the animals to extract venom. He becomes bitten. The head researcher has no choice but to try the most recent untested serum on the young man. To everyone's amazement it works! But, after trying it again on other victims it doesn't.  Nobody can figure out why.

The story then goes on as the government continues to be frustrated in developing the planet. However, an interesting plot twist comes out towards the end which I have always remembered. It was a good story and I would enjoy reading it again.

Plot twist:

> we find out that instead of being 100% fatal, there is actually a very tiny percentage of men that can survive the bite. those that do, live incredibly long, healthy lives even outliving their own children and grandchildren. They obviously reproduce more often than those that die, thus passing on their genes and immunity to the bite. This is discovered after finding that the natives have a special secret "coming of age ritual" for their young males. They are sent to an island in which they live with the animal and it bites them. Most survive (the gene is present enough to prevent most from dying). But, only a few live such long lives to pass on their genes. That is why the remnant colony is starting to grow. Hence, we also find out the original young research who was bitten was not saved by the serum. instead, he was "saved" because of his genetic resistance. During the course of the story he turns from a stereotypical nerdy weakling to a strong, healthy young man who eventually realizes what a gift he has been given.

As always, any help finding it would be greatly appreciated.